# Image file uploader plugin for Rails 3.2 that can store to Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, rubygems, paperclip, carrierwave

I'm looking for Rails plugin that can store image file to database.

I've just try "paperclip" and "carrierwave".

They are good plugin.

But they normaly can store to local file system or Amazon S3, fog.

I want to store image file to database.

Please tell me which gem can accomplish it.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example how to you can store an image in binary field (`raw_file`)

form:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  # store uploaded avatar as blob
  @user.raw_file = params[:user][:avatar].read
  @user.save
end
```

Use [RMagick](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#from_blob) or [mini_magick](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mini_magick/MiniMagick/Image#read-class_method) to convert image from blob.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting to change my mind not to use plugins. I decided to store image data in database directly.